# Google Captcha expiration time

Tags: javascript, html

I want to increase expiration time of google captcha but I could not find a solution to handle it. I have used the reset method but it's default expiration time(2 minutes) does not let me to control it.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    grecaptcha.reset();
}, 1200000);
```

Is there any way to do what I'm looking for?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param)

Comment: That was not my answer. I read it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set timeout was not good solution for google Captcha. it was better to reset google captcha when session timeout .  use the callback function  expired-callback

```
  <script>
       var callback = function() {
          grecaptcha.render('element', {
             'sitekey': 'your-site-key',
             'expired-callback': fnCallback
           });
       };
       var fnCallback = function() {
          grecaptcha.reset();
       };
    </script>
```